# AWS DynamoDb local - asks for region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am working through the examples and I simply can't listen the tables like in the given cli example.

My cli parameters

```
java -Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -inMemory

aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
```

Then it always asks me for a region and points me to "aws configure". When I entered nothing in the credentials and local as region I get:

```
Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".
```

What am I doing wrong? I just want to play around locally to get more familiar with the cli interface before I use the cloud itself. Bugs me a but that I cant get it work.

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When running DynamoDB local, you don't need valid keys, but do put a valid region. For example, when running aws configure put any key for aws access key id, any key for aws secret access key and type us-east-1 or us-west-1 etc for regions.
Try running again the command, it should work.

Comment: That was it. Also had to put some fake key into the configuration. Very odd, but I am glad it works now. Thank you very much!